# nil class error on post process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, omniauth

```
class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @identity = Identity.new
    # @identity = env['omniauth.identity']
  end
end
```

my signup form is:

```
=simple_form_for( :identity, url: "/auth/identity/register", :html => { id: :signup_form, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|

  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          input#name placeholder="name" type="text" f.name

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-envelope
          input#email placeholder="email" type="text" f.email 

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-key
          input#password placeholder="password" type="password"

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-key
          input#password_confirmation placeholder="password confirmation" type="password"


  .form-actions
    .control-group
      .controls
        = f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary'
```

my identity model

```
class Identity
  include Mongoid::Document
  include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid

  field :name,              type: String
  field :email,             type: String
  field :password_digest,   type: String

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 8, maximum: 16
end
```

i use omniauth-identity gem.  my identity model, identities_controller  and identity/new view like above. When i click the register button, it gives `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` error. I looked at console and values post. it shows

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass):
  omniauth-identity (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/identity/secure_password.rb:71:in `password='
```

how can i solve this problem? i wait your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using an older version of omniauth-identity. There's a commit on the omniauth github page from about a year ago that seems to fix the issue you're experiencing.

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity/commit/7efa2ae9fd44f27df09e167b5a93a62332512e0c

Try updating the gem to the latest version and see if it works better.